# Print array in table make two columns

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code. And i need to print the data from the array. Problems is i Designed the table to have 2 columns , one with name and second with count. And i don't know how to print the values in two columns.

```
 class Tabel{
        private $tabel = array();
        public function getElemente(){
            $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');  /
            $db_selected = mysql_select_db('world',$conn);  
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT  c.Continent, COUNT(c.Name) FROM country c
                                    GROUP BY c.Continent    
                                    Order By COUNT(c.Name) desc");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                //echo $row['Continent'] . " " . $row['COUNT(c.Name)']."<br>";
                $this->tabel[]=$row['Continent']. " " . $row['COUNT(c.Name)'];

            }


        }
        public function afisare(){
        print_r($this->tabel);
            echo"<table border=1 cellpading=0 cellspacing=0 >";
            echo"<th>Continent</th>";
            echo"<th>Tari</th>";
            foreach($this->tabel as $value){
                echo"<tr>";
                echo"<td>".$value."</td>";
                echo"</tr>";
            }


        }
```

I thought at matrix .. and asociative array. I tried some ideas..but no luck. Syntax is killing me.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change some things:

- Your variable $table could be an multidimensional array.
- To make this multidimensional array work you have to check your sql-statement
- Last but not least you have to make some changes to your foreach-function.

Let's start with your SQL-Statement:
Additionally to Continent and count select the continent-id.

Use this continentId as key in your $table variable. Your code might look like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT  c.ContinentId, c.Continent, COUNT(c.Name) as count FROM country c
                       GROUP BY c.Continent    
                       Order By COUNT(c.Name) desc");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $this->tabel[$row['ContinentId']]['continent'] = $row['Continent'];
    $this->tabel[$row['ContinentId']]['count'] = $row['count'];
}
```

Note: for your column "COUNT(c.Name)" I give an alias ("count").

With these new informations in your $table-variable you have the possibility to edit the foreach:

```
echo"<table border=1 cellpading=0 cellspacing=0 >";
echo"<th>Continent</th>";
echo"<th>Tari</th>";
foreach($this->tabel as $key=>$value){
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>".$value['continent']."</td>";
    echo"<td>".$value['count']."</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
}
```

This should do the work for you.

Besides that: 
If you could I would lookout if there is any way to prevent echo any data from out of your class.

Comment: its not good. i get some weird error regarding undefined index. i did this:  private $tabel = array(array());     and ... i get this:  Notice: Undefined index: continent in... and otice: Undefined index: count in... at  afisare()

Comment: Did you add the following line to your while-loop: `$this->table[$row['ContinentId']]['count'] = $row['count'];`

Comment: There is a typo! Look at line 21. you wrote `table` but your variable is called `tabel`.